# calling C++ function from fortran not C

Tags: fortran

is it possible to call a C++ function from FORTRAN such as

```
#include <iostream.h>
extern "C"
{
    void single_cell(void)
    {
        cout<<"Hi from C++";
    }
}
```

So when I am using C it is working fine but with the C++ function it gives errors like 
Undefined error to cout  etc

Comment: You would need `using namespace std;` or `std::cout` but i dont think this will work in an `extern "C"`

Comment: I'a not sure but maybe you must `include<iostream>` and use `std::cout`, but I don't know it will be working

Comment: You will need to edit the question to explain which C++ and fortran compilers you are using and how you are doing the linking before anyone can give you a definitive answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both g++ and gfortran, used as linkers, bring in extra libraries.  That is why the Fortran/C++ combination is trickier than the Fortran/C combination ... just using the correct compiler as the linker won't work, you need to add a libary.   Already suggested is to link with gfortran and specify the C++ runtime libraries.   You can also link with g++ and specify the Fortran runtime libraries.   See [Linking fortran and c++ binaries using gcc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5663083/linking-fortran-and-c-binaries-using-gcc) for the details of both approaches.

Comment: g++ main.o print_hi.o -o main -lgfortran after using this command it gives the error as                                                                      /cygnus/cygwin-b20/H-i586-cygwin32/i586-cygwin32/bin/1d cannot open -lgfortran: no such a file or director                                                                                                                                        what is the exact procedure to include the path because i think the gfortran is installed in some other directory

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you could have your Fortran code call into a C function, the problem is not the code but rather how you are linking. When you're linking C++ objects you need to also pull in the C++ runtime. If using GCC, link with the g++ command and it will pull in the parts you need.

Comment: Linking with g++ (and doing nothing else) will just result in the fortran runtime libraries not being found. The solution is either to link with the fortran compiler and add the C++ runtime libraries to the link statement, or link with the C++ compiler and add the fortran runtime libraries to the link statement. Both will work.

Comment: @  talonmies yes you are right. The prblem is in the linking phase and i am uisng the gfortran commands so it is gives problem with the C++ cout. can you please give detail how i include the libraries in the linking command

Comment: I am using Iso_c_binding in fortran for calling this C++ funciton, which works fine in the case of C but not in the C++