# gfortran undefined references

Tags: c++, fortran, g++, linker-errors, gfortran

I'm trying to compile a program that depends on a lot of things.
I use and modify the makefile provided to stand for my computer settings, but I keep getting a lot of undefined references in the last step of compilation.

The command line that causes the troubles is:

```
gfortran -o ../cosmomc ParamNames.o Matrix_utils.o  settings.o IO.o cmbtypes.o Planck_like.o cmbdata.o WeakLen.o &
bbn.o lrggettheory.o mpk.o bao.o supernovae.o HST.o SDSSLy-a-v3.o CMB_Cls_simple.o paramdef.o propose.o params_CMB.o &
calclike.o EstCovmat.o PowellConstrainedMinimize.o minimize.o postprocess.o MCMC.o driver.o /home/darkside/tesis/CosmoMc &
/likelihood_v4p1/read_archive_map.o /home/darkside/tesis/CosmoMc/likelihood_v4p1/read_fits.o /home/darkside/tesis/CosmoMc/likelihood_v4p1/healpix_types.o /home/darkside/tesis &
/CosmoMc/likelihood_v4p1/WMAP_7yr_options.o /home/darkside/tesis/CosmoMc/likelihood_v4p1/WMAP_7yr_util.o /home/darkside/tesis &
/CosmoMc/likelihood_v4p1/WMAP_7yr_tt_pixlike.o /home/darkside/tesis/CosmoMc/likelihood_v4p1/WMAP_7yr_teeebb_pixlike.o /home/darkside/tesis/CosmoMc &
/likelihood_v4p1/WMAP_7yr_likelihood.o /home/darkside/tesis /CosmoMc/likelihood_v4p1/WMAP_7yr_gibbs.o /home/darkside/tesis &
/CosmoMc/likelihood_v4p1/WMAP_7yr_tt_beam_ptsrc_chisq.o /home/darkside/tesis/CosmoMc/likelihood_v4p1/br_mod_dist.o &

-L../camb -lcamb_cosmorec -lblas -llapack -L/usr/lib/gcc & 
/i686-linux-gnu/4.4/ -lstdc++ -L../CosmoRec -lCosmoRec &
-L/usr/lib -lgsl -lgslcblas  -L/usr/lib/i386-linux/gnu/lib &
-L/home/darkside/tesis/CosmoMc/likelihood_v4p1 -lcfitsio &
-DMATRIX_SINGLE -O3 -fopenmp -ffree-form -x f95-cpp-input  &
-ffast-math -march=native -funroll-loops -DCOSMOREC -I../camb &
-I/usr/lib/i386-linux/gnu/include -I/home/darkside/tesis/CosmoMc/likelihood_v4p1
```

And some errors are:

```
../CosmoRec/libCosmoRec.a(CosmoRec.o): In function `__tcf_0':
 CosmoRec.cpp:(.text+0xb): undefined reference to `std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>,  
 std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()'
 CosmoRec.cpp:(.text+0x17): undefined reference to `std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>,
 std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()'
 ../CosmoRec/libCosmoRec.a(CosmoRec.o): In function `__tcf_1':
 CosmoRec.cpp:(.text+0x47): undefined reference to `std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, 
 std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()'
 ../CosmoRec/libCosmoRec.a(CosmoRec.o): In function `std::_Vector_base<double, std::allocator<double> 
  >::_M_deallocate(double*, unsigned int) [clone .isra.76]':
```

All of them are in the package compiled in g++, so I guess the problem can be the lstdc++ flag. I tried to add the complete path to the library and other options, but it doesn't work.

Any help would be really aprecciated.

Regards,
Illa

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Linking Fortran and C++ binaries using gcc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5663083/linking-fortran-and-c-binaries-using-gcc)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried putting `-lstdc++` at th *end* of the link command?  It needs to come *after* any objects and libraries that depend on it.

Comment: You are right. Changing the order works. I was using a given Makefile, so I changed it in there. Thanks.