# Undefined reference to `std::chrono::_V2::system_clock::now()' when linking with gfortran

Tags: c++, linker, fortran, c++14, gfortran

I am trying to create an user defined block in INSEL which requires C++ to program and I link it using gfortran.

I have the following code in my program

```
// Setting seed for random number generators
unsigned seed = static_cast<int> (std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count());
```

to set as a seed to my random number generator. When i compile it using g++ (gcc v.5.1.0) it shows no error or warning. My compiling command is

```
g++ -O0 -Wall -c -g3 -std=c++14 -fmessage-length=0 $(sourcesC)
```

sourcecC has all my .cpp programs. BUt when I try linking it using gfortran with:

```
gfortran -shared -o C:\***\inselUB.dll -Wall -L./ -linselTools $(objects)
```

I get an error:

> C:***\resources/../src/constants.h:54: undefined reference to
>   `std::chrono::_V2::system_clock::now()'
>
> collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status makefile:11: recipe for
>   target 'inselUB' failed
>
> make: *** [inselUB] Error 1

I am just a beginner to this type of interfacing. may be its a simple error. Could anyone suggest me an solution?

OS: Win 7

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Linking Fortran and C++ binaries using gcc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5663083/linking-fortran-and-c-binaries-using-gcc)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally you need to link `-lstdc++` when linking C++ objects with gfortran. If you linked with g++ you would have to link `-lgfortran`.